# ASP.Net MVC web app, Unity and assembly with AutoMapper

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, unity-container, automapper

I have an ASP.Net MVC web app that's referencing an assembly that is using AutoMapper.
The web app is using Unity for dependency injection. The assembly is also using Unity. The AutoMapper is also using Unity in the configuration. The Unity container is created by the web app and it's shared to the assembly.

When the web app tries to load, I get an error that it can't resolve my DTO class "Folder". The "Folder" class is not used yet in this part of the web app.
My guess is because there's a reference to "Folder" by AutoMapper and they share the same Unity container.

Does this mean that the web app needs a reference to AutoMapper?

This is the registration of the assembly in the web app:

```
globalContainer.RegisterType<IDataRoomFoldersServices, DataRoomFoldersServices>(new TransientLifetimeManager());
```

This is the AutoMapper configure method:

```
    public static void Configure(ISimpleContainer unityContainer)
    {
        container = unityContainer;
        if (isConfigured == false)
        {
            lock (sync)
            {
                if (isConfigured == false)
                {                                                          
                    mapConfiguration.ForEach(map => map.Configure());
                    isConfigured = true;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

This is portion of the AutoMapper configuration:

```
            Mapper.CreateMap<FolderRequest, Folder>()
            .ForMember(dest => dest.CreatedDate, src => src.Ignore())
            .ForMember(dest => dest.ModifiedDate, src => src.Ignore())
            .ForMember(dest => dest.FolderId, src => src.Ignore());
```

Comment: You haven't indicated how you partitioned your application but you would need an AutoMapper reference in your web app if you ever intend to do _any_ kind of mapping in your web app e.g. `Mapper.Map<ViewModel>(dtoModel)`.

Comment: AutoMapper is only used in the assembly. The web app doesn't use AutoMapper because it has its own mapping mechanism. The facade of the assembly accepts DTO model.